# Enable CI secret variables inside ecosystem.config?

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

How can I use secret variables inside my ecosystem.config.js?

So this is inside my gitlab-ci.yml file. I can access secret variables via "$...":

```
....

- echo "$AWS_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
- ssh-add <(echo "$RUNNER_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

  ...
script:
- pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.js production
```

My ecosystem.config looks like this:

```
apps: [{
    name: 'test',
    script: './test.js',
    env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
    env: {
     "test_ENV": "$MY_SECRET_VARIABLE" // not working
    }
}],
```

So I want to set env variables to make them available inside node via process.env.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm also curious!

Answer (score 0):

This might work! I just found it, but haven't tested yet.

https://github.com/icehaunter/pm2-better-deploy

> Adds save_env deployment setup config key. It can be an array of strings or an object. All elements are filled from environment variables where the deployment command was run and saved into the config on the deployment server. This allows to "pass" environment vars, like secrets from the gitlab runner instance to the pm2 instance